# Python: memory usage while writing to a file (generator vs list)

Tags: python, list, memory-management, generator

I'm trying to create a list of file names from a large tarball file and I would like to understand why the memory usage is still the same in my example? Is it because `f.write()` is still holding/buffering all objects in memory before the file is actually closed? Is there a way to improve this?

```
# touch file{1..100000}.txt
# tar cf test.tar file*
```

**Generator**

```
# python test.py 
Memory (Before): 40.918MB
Memory (After): 117.066MB
It took 12.636950492858887 seconds.
```

**List:**

```
# python test.py
Memory (Before): 40.918MB
Memory (After): 117.832MB
It took 12.049121856689453 seconds.
```

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import memory_profiler
import tarfile
import time


def files_generator(tar):
    entry = tar.next()
    while entry:
        yield entry.name
        entry = tar.next()

def files_list(tar):
    return tar.getnames()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'Memory (Before): {memory_profiler.memory_usage()[0]:.3f}MB')
    start = time.time()
    tar = tarfile.open('test.tar')
    with open('output_g.txt', 'w') as f:
        for i in files_generator(tar):
        #for i in files_list(tar):
            f.write(i + '\n')
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Memory (After): {memory_profiler.memory_usage()[0]:.3f}MB')
    print(f'It took {end-start} seconds.')
```

Comment: Have you tried flushing to disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tarfile.next()` method caches its contents, [including the lines](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/23e65b25557f957af840cf8fe68e80659ce28629/Lib/tarfile.py#L2299):

```
if tarinfo is not None: 
    self.members.append(tarinfo)
```

It turns out that `Tarfile.getnames()` calls `Tarfile.getmembers()` which calls `Tarfile._load()` which repeatedly calls `Tarfile.next()` until all is read into `self.members`.  So `Tarfile.getnames()` and iterating via `Tarfile.next()` will have the same memory usage.

Comment: @HTF: If you want to get around this override the `Tarfile.next()` method with a subclass and stop it from caching.  Just copy the code from the method in the existing class and omit the offending lines.  Note that this will totally break `Tarfile` except for your intended usage (because everything uses `next()`).